# Does the change of router parameter in React Route path cause remount of Component and other initial render respectively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a question about react router. I'm using different paths for the same component. The path is different since a changeable route parameter is given inside. So, does the change of the parameter causes the component to remount/unmount? If yes, does the remount of the component cause an initial render again? (I'm using functional components. I'm building a chatapp. There will be different chatrooms and the user can navigate to them from the home component.)

```
import './Home.css'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min';
import ChatRoom from './ChatRoom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const Home = ({db, auth, user}) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [user1, setUser1] = useState('Loading...');
    const logOut = () => {
        auth.signOut().then(() => {
            history.replace("/");
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('users').get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                if (doc.id === user.uid) {
                    setUser1(doc.data().username);
                }
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <Router>
           <div>
            <Link to="/rooms/ChatA">ChatA</Link>
            <Link to="/rooms/ChatB">ChatB</Link>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/rooms/:ChatID">
                <ChatRoom db={db} auth={auth}/>
              </Route>
            <Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>

     )
  }
export default Home;
```

This is the component where the user will navigate to particular chatroom from.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import {firebase} from '../../Firebase/firebase';


const ChatRoom = ({ db, auth }) => {
    const { chatID } = useParams();
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [docs, setDocs] = useState(null)
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
    const dummy = useRef();
    const sendMsg = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        db.collection(chatID).add({
            username: user,
            text: msg,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        }).then(() => {
            dummy.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        })
        setMsg('');
    }
    const deleteMsg = (id) => {
        db.collection(chatID).doc(id).delete();
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                db.collection('users').get().then(snapshot => {
                    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                        if (doc.id === user.uid) {
                            setUser(doc.data().username);
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        })
                          
    
   db.collection(chatID).orderBy('createdAt').onSnapshot(snapshot) 
    => {
            setDocs(snapshot.docs);}
}, [])

    return (
        <div>
          //some contents
        </div>
    );
}
export default ChatRoom;
```

This is the component which will be mounted according to which chatroom the user will navigate to.

I'll repeat my question: Will the change of the route parameter value cause a remount of the ChatRoom component and cause another initial render respectively?

Comment: A `console.log` placed in your `ChatRoom` component will answer your question. But I have a feeling (could be wrong) you're actually wondering why your `onAuthStateChanged` is being called again - it's because you didn't specify dependencies in your effect so it gets run on every render.

Comment: I tried it and it was running the ```console.log``` each time I navigate from one route to another. Doesn't it mean that React each time renders the chatroom component? And shouldn't the component render the content again and trigger the useEffect respectively?

Comment: It is supposed to render the component each time. As for triggering useEffect - a render will call that effect based on the dependencies - see [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). You have specified no dependencies - `[]` - means your effect will run on mount of that component only. What is the actual problem you're running into?